# CSS background image is not loaded on localhost using Node.js

Tags: css, node.js, background-image

I have tried many of those solved examples, but I am not able to solve the problem. Everything is showing on localhost except for the background image. I have used sendFile() for referencing style.css file.

test.js

```
var express = require("express");
var app     = express();
var path    = require("path");
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.static('image')); //I am not sure about this line.


app.get('/index.html',function(req, res){
res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/index.html'));
});

app.get('/style.css', function(req, res){
res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/style.css'));
});
```

style.css

```
.container-home {
width: 100%;
height: 30em;
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
transition: background-size 2s ease-in-out 1s;
background-image: url(image/Greenery.jpg);
background-size: 100%;
background-position: center;
position: relative;
}
```

File Structure

```
Code
 |_ tree
      |_ image
          |_ Greenery.png
```

Comment: Check the network tab to see what is the URL being requested for the image

Comment: Is `Code` a folder or the root of project?

Comment: Hi, Code is the root of the project.

Comment: The request url shown on the network tab is  http://localhost:3000/image/Greenery.jpg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html):

> Express looks up the files relative to the static directory, so the name of the static directory is not part of the URL.

So in your case, since you are making `images` the static directory, it shouldn't be in the URL. Your CSS is currently including it: `localhost:3000/image/Greenery.jpg.` .

I'd change `background-image: url(image/Greenery.jpg);` to
`background-image: url(Greenery.jpg);`

---

Or you can try creating a virtual path prefix like this without editing the CSS:

```
app.use('/image', express.static('image'))
```

Also note this part:

> However, the path that you provide to the express.static function is relative to the directory from where you launch your node process. If you run the express app from another directory, it’s safer to use the absolute path of the directory that you want to serve:

So in your case it should be something like:

```
const path = require('path')
app.use('/image', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'tree', 'image')))
```

Comment: The image still disappeared from it.

Comment: @AlonsoTan check the updated part of the answer at the bottom

Comment: The second method should handle your current request `localhost:3000/image/Greenery.jpg.`

Comment: Hi, it still does not work. I am unsure of where is the problem.

Comment: @AlonsoTan did you restart the server? are you starting it from the root of the project? Does the request URL change when you change the CSS?

Comment: test.js is located inside the tree folder, so I run 'cd tree', followed by 'node test.js'.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235001/discussion-between-alonso-tan-and-t-j).

Answer (score 0):

change you project structure to something like this

```
--- root
  --- server.js
  --- public
   --- styles
     --- style.css
```

now change you static line to this

```
app.use(express.static('public')); // this tells express serve static assets here to the user
```

now when you navigate to `localhost/styles/style.css` you get you css file and you don't have to specify a route for it so you can remove this from you code

```
//remove this
app.get('/style.css', function(req, res){
res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/style.css'));
});
```